# Finding higher and lower numbers in an array and storing in one array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get the closest lowest and highest to a number.

#### Attempt

```
<?php
    $a = array(1, 8, 23,42,47, 52, 55, 66, 74,75, 76,77,78, 95,);
    sort($a);
    $v = 58;    
    $lesser = null;
    $greater = null;
    foreach($a as $key => $current){
        if($current <= $v){
            $lesser     = $current;
            $greater    = $a[($key+1)];
        }else{

        }
    }
        print_r(array(
            "lesser"    => $lesser,
            "greater"   => $greater,
        ));  
?>
    /** output :
    Array 
   (
     lesser => 55
     greater => 66
    )
    **/
```

My aim is to get all the numbers greater to the given number, and the same with the lesser:

```
greater => 66, 74, 75, 77, 78, 95
lesser => 55, 52, 47, 42, 23, 8, 1
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `$lesser` and `$greater` arrays that you push onto, instead of replacing.

```
<?php
$a = array(1, 8, 23,42,47, 52, 55, 66, 74,75, 76,77,78, 95,);
$v = 58;    
$lesser = [];
$greater = [];
foreach($a as $key => $current){
    if ($current < $v) {
        $lesser[] = $current;
    } elseif ($current > $v) {
        $greater[] = $current;
    }
}
print_r(array(
    "lesser"    => $lesser,
    "greater"   => $greater,
));  
?>
```